# Getting a "subproject commit" message when I send a pull request, and I'm told to merge in the upstream changes. What do I do?

Tags: git, github

When I sent a pull request for my changes to a repo, I get this: `+ Subproject commit: *numbers*` and I was told to try to merge in the upstream changes.

How exactly do I go about doing this? I tried using `git fetch origin` into my local repo, then mergetool, but it says: `No files need merging`.

Comment: A link to the pull request would be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/Islandora/islandora_simple_workflow/pull/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being asked to update your branch with changes made to the project since you forked your branch.  For example the project history might look like this now:

```
A  <- master
|
B  E  <-- Your branch which you submitted as a pull request.
|  |
C  D
| /
F   <-- You fork your branch and start working.
```

Note that there are now commits (A, B, and C) which are not in your branch history.  The last common commit between your branch and `master` is `F`.  The project maintainer wants you to merge A, B, and C into your branch so the history of your branch looks something like this:

```
   M  <-- New tip of your branch.
  /|
 / |
A  <- master
|  |
B  E  
|  |
C  D
| /
F   <-- You fork your branch and start working.
```

This way if there are conflicts between `A, B, C` and your commits `E, D` you will have to resolve them.  Then the project maintainer can merge your pull request without needing to resolve conflicts by merging commit `M`.

To do this update origin as you have then checkout your branch and run the command `git merge origin/master` (assuming master is upstream HEAD).  Then if there are conflicts run `git mergetool` and it will walk you through conflict resolution.  Commit your merge and update your pull request with the merged commit.

If you've not read it already I highly recommend the online git book.  [Here is the section on branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).